# How to stop God from leaving stale Resque worker processes?

Tags: ruby, resque, god

I'm trying to understand how to monitor the resque worker for [travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci) with god in such a way that stopping the resque watch via god won't leave a stale worker process.

In the following I'm talking about the worker process, not forked job child processes (i.e. the queue is empty all the time).

When I manually start the resque worker like this:

```
$ QUEUE=builds rake resque:work
```

I'll get a single process:

```
$ ps x | grep resque
 7041 s001  S+     0:05.04 resque-1.13.0: Waiting for builds
```

And this process will go away as soon as I stop the worker task.

But when I start the same thing with god ([exact configuration is here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/blob/master/config/resque.god.example), basically the same thing as the [resque/god example](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/examples/god/resque.god)) like this ...

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development god -c config/resque.god -D
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: Loading config/resque.god
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: Syslog enabled.
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: Using pid file directory: /Volumes/Users/sven/.god/pids
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: Started on drbunix:///tmp/god.17165.sock
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 move 'init' to 'start'
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 start: cd /Volumes/Users/sven/Development/projects/travis && rake resque:work
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'init' to 'start'
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 move 'start' to 'up'
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 [ok] memory within bounds [784kb] (MemoryUsage)
I [2011-03-27 22:49:15]  INFO: resque-0 [ok] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2011-03-27 22:49:45]  INFO: resque-0 [ok] memory within bounds [784kb, 784kb] (MemoryUsage)
I [2011-03-27 22:49:45]  INFO: resque-0 [ok] process is running (ProcessRunning)
```

Then I'll get an extra process:

```
$ ps x | grep resque
 7187   ??  Ss     0:00.02 sh -c cd /Volumes/Users/sven/Development/projects/travis && rake resque:work
 7188   ??  S      0:05.11 resque-1.13.0: Waiting for builds
 7183 s001  S+     0:01.18 /Volumes/Users/sven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby /Volumes/Users/sven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/god -c config/resque.god -D
```

God only seems to log the pid of the first one:

```
$ cat ~/.god/pids/resque-0.pid
7187
```

When I then stop the resque watch via god:

```
$ god stop resque
Sending 'stop' command

The following watches were affected:
  resque-0
```

God gives this log output:

```
I [2011-03-27 22:51:22]  INFO: resque-0 stop: default lambda killer
I [2011-03-27 22:51:22]  INFO: resque-0 sent SIGTERM
I [2011-03-27 22:51:23]  INFO: resque-0 process stopped
I [2011-03-27 22:51:23]  INFO: resque-0 move 'up' to 'unmonitored'
I [2011-03-27 22:51:23]  INFO: resque-0 moved 'up' to 'unmonitored'
```

But it does not actually terminate both of the processes, leaving the actual worker process alive:

```
$ ps x | grep resque
 6864   ??  S      0:05.15 resque-1.13.0: Waiting for builds
 6858 s001  S+     0:01.36 /Volumes/Users/sven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby /Volumes/Users/sven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/god -c config/resque.god -D
```

Comment: God will always spawn zombies, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Hmm, if that's true, then what's the point of the `god stop` command?

Comment: @svenfuchs: Sometimes the answer is no.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to tell god to use pid file generated by rescue and set pid file

```
w.env = {'PIDFILE' => '/path/to/resque.pid'}
w.pid_file = '/path/to/resque.pid'
```

env will tell rescue to write pid file, and pid_file will tell god to use it

also as svenfuchs noted it should be enough to set only proper env:

```
w.env = { 'PIDFILE' => "/home/travis/.god/pids/#{w.name}.pid" }
```

where /home/travis/.god/pids is the default pids directory

Comment: Actually I can't get it to run if I set w.pid_file. It works just using `w.env = { 'PIDFILE' => "/home/travis/.god/pids/#{w.name}.pid" }` though (where `/home/travis/.god/pids` is the default pids directory).

Comment: holy crap... that works, but as svenfuchs says, with the w.env and not the w.pid_file.  I also needed to set God.pid_file_directory = "/my/path/to/pids"

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I think that's because I have god running as root, but I have it start my resque processes with a different user. When resque tries to write to the pidfile it doesn't have permission to do so...

Comment: @kevinrutherford make sure to create one dir in which the user can write - that should not be that hard

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party here but we had the same issue on our side. We were using

```
rvm 2.1.0@ do bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

which caused the multiple processes. According to our sysops guy this is due to the usage of **rvm do** which we ended up replacing with

```
/path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

This allowed god to work as expected without the need to specify the pid file.